# PySpark RDD filter trouble with inequality

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD called `bank_rdd` which has been imported from a CSV file.

First I have split each line separated by a comma into a list

```
bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
```

The header titles are:

```
accountNumber, personFname, personLname, balance
```

I then removed the header

```
header = bank_rdd1.first()
bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd1.filter(lambda row: row != header)
```

Sample data for the first two records as follows:

```
[('1','John','Smith','1100'),('2','Jane','Doe','500')]
```

When I run the following code I get a count of 100 (which is the amount of records before I filter)

```
bank_rdd1.count()
```

When I run the following code I get a count of 0. Note that x[3] refers to the column that contains bank account balances and it is a string.

```
bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd1.filter(lambda x: int(x[3]) > 1000)
bank_rdd1.count()
```

I'm not sure why it is returning a count of 0, when in the CSV file there are 20 rows where the bank account balance is greater than 1000.

Could anybody point out what the error may be?

Comment: Where is your RDD or CSV? How can we figure it out?

Comment: I'm reading from a CSV using textFile function. bank_rdd = sc.textFile('bank.csv')

Comment: Show your sample. I DONT KNOW YOUR DATA.

Comment: Provided some sample data.

Comment: `rdd = sc.parallelize([('1','John','Smith','1100'),('2','Jane','Doe','500')])` and `rdd.filter(lambda x: int(x[3]) > 1000).count()` gives me the count 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works just fine for me.

```py
>>> data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('1','John','Smith','1100'),('2','Jane','Doe','500')])
>>> data.first()
('1', 'John', 'Smith', '1100')
>>> data.count()
2
>>> data.filter(lambda x: int(x[3]) > 1000).count()
1
```

Are you sure this is causing the error? Can you share whole code? Can you tell about your pyspark envirnment?